# Use Rhino Service Bus on ASP.NET website with Ninject

Tags: asp.net, dependency-injection, ninject, servicebus, rhino-servicebus

I will like to add Rhino Service Bus to my ASP.NET web application but using Ninject as the DI Container. So far all examples I keep seeing use Castle Windsor which I don't want to use since we already use Ninject.

Are there any tutorials out there which show how to add Rhino Service Bus to an ASP.NET web application without a direct dependency on Castle Windsor (e.g. using Ninject)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you'd have to start by rewriting [RhinoServiceBusFacility](http://github.com/ayende/rhino-esb/blob/master/Rhino.ServiceBus/Impl/RhinoServiceBusFacility.cs) / [AbstractRhinoServiceBusFacility](http://github.com/ayende/rhino-esb/blob/master/Rhino.ServiceBus/Impl/AbstractRhinoServiceBusFacility.cs) as a Ninject module. Then there are also Castle references in other files, e.g. [DefaultServiceBus](http://github.com/ayende/rhino-esb/blob/master/Rhino.ServiceBus/Impl/DefaultServiceBus.cs) has references to IKernel which should be changed to use Ninject's kernel instead.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays, Rhino Service Bus (RSB) does not directly depend on Castle. Modules are available for integration with [Autofac](http://nuget.org/packages/Rhino.ServiceBus.Autofac), [Spring.net](http://nuget.org/packages/Rhino.ServiceBus.Spring), [Unity](http://nuget.org/packages/Rhino.ServiceBus.Unity), [StructureMap](http://nuget.org/packages/Rhino.ServiceBus.StructureMap) and of course [Castle](http://nuget.org/packages/Rhino.ServiceBus.Castle).

Ninject isn't supported yet; you can use the [Castle implementation](https://github.com/hibernating-rhinos/rhino-esb/tree/master/Rhino.ServiceBus.Castle) as a reference implementation.